# How can I disable flake8 for a multiline import?

Tags: python, pyflakes

With flake8, to disable a certain error on a line you do this:

```
example = lambda: 'example'  # noqa: E731,E123
```

However, if I have ***multiline a statement, flake8 fails*** to parse the noqa statment at the end:

```
from detect_fixtures import expected_response_stage3_mocked, expected_response_bbox_oob,\
    mock_detection, mock_detection_models, mock_detection_stage1, mock_detection_stage2,\
    mock_detection_stage3_given_bbox, mock_load_image  # noqa: F401
```

I want to use '\' for continuation, so I don't want to do this (which does work)

```
from detect_fixtures import (expected_response_stage3_mocked,  # noqa: F401                      
    expected_response_bbox_oob, img, mock_detection, mock_detection_models,  # noqa: F401        
    mock_detection_stage1, mock_detection_stage2, mock_detection_stage3_given_bbox,  # noqa: F401
    mock_load_image)  # noqa: F401
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
from detect_fixtures import (expected_response_stage3_mocked,  # noqa: F401                      
    expected_response_bbox_oob, img, mock_detection, mock_detection_models,  
    mock_detection_stage1, mock_detection_stage2, mock_detection_stage3_given_bbox,
    mock_load_image)
```

You only need one noqa. Flake8 views continuation lines as a single one.

Comment: Odd, this doesn't work for me. E.g.: `print("a long string" # noqa <NEWLINE> "a long string")`. The second line isn't ignored.

Comment: Also doesn't work for a string inside a `""" longline\n longline\n """` structure